# Casting big NSInteger to float issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, floating-point, nsinteger

1) define big NSInteger
2) cast to float
3) log float
4) turns into slightly smaller number every time???

```
NSInteger val = 485935336;
float val_float = (float)val;
NSLog(@"%f", val_float); //logs 485935328, not 485935336
```

---

Any clue why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any idea why? Of course. float has about six digits of precision. double has 15 digits precision, which is why you should always use double unless you can give a good reason why not. You will get the same problem, but only when the numbers are a lot bigger.

Comment: Sorry I had code that was doing something different with proprietary information in it, when I was posting here I quickly swapped it out with @(485935336) and hit "post", I'll use double and see if I can get this working :D